# How to change style for a single LayoutDocument?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, avalondock

Suppose I have this xaml:

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager>
    <avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
        <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
                    <avalonDock:LayoutDocument Title="Main Panel">
                    </avalonDock:LayoutDocument>
                </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
                <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
                    <avalonDock:LayoutDocument Title="Panel 02">
                    </avalonDock:LayoutDocument>
                </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
                <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
                    <avalonDock:LayoutDocument Title="Panel 03">
                    </avalonDock:LayoutDocument>
                </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
                <!-- 
                Other LayoutDocumentPane's here...
                -->
            </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
        </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
    </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
</avalonDock:DockingManager>
```

Now I need put a different style only for "Main Panel", by example, a red background. All other panels ("Panel 02", "Panel 03", etc...) must be unchanged. All samples I found are to change the entire theme, but I need change only one LayoutDocument element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DataTemplates`, `TemplateSelector`, or `Converters` and you need to give them something that can differantiate between the items you want to change and those you do not want to change.

A [WPF Converter](https://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) on the style property could, for example, use the Title (if its unique across your app) to return a corresponding style for each document. But this would be a very poor implementation - use an enumeration property in the class to make this one more robust.

An even better solution is the usage of a `TemplateSelector` based on a class hierarchy of inherating classes over your document viewmodel - but this is more involved - but there are some samples to look at: [Here is one that does the same for LayoutAnchorables](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock/blob/7c742404fa8ec6f758ecbf639e6642208f642f73/source/MLibTest/MLibTest/MainWindow.xaml#L109).

Answer (score 1):

You might simply change the `Style`  of `LayoutDocument` adding a `DataTrigger` that would change background color basing on a property set on your ViewModel.

That property should be set to `true` (if the logic behind is binary but should be more complex if needed) just on the ViewModel of your `MainPanel`.

Please have a look to the `Theme.xaml` of `AvalonDock` and search for `<Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:LayoutDocumentTabItem}">`. Inside that style you can easily access The ViewModel binded to any `TabItem` by simply access `{Binding LayoutItem.Model.<my_property>`